# Does V8 have function signatures like Local<Value> Get(Local<Value>)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, node.js-addon, embedded-v8

I am learning Node C++ Addon and found that the following code can be run on Node v8.9.3

```
void test(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();

    Local<Object> obj = Local<Object>::Cast(args[0]);
    Local<Value> v8_string = obj->Get(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "string"));
    Local<Value> v8_int = obj->Get(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "int"));
    Local<Value> v8_float = obj->Get(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "float"));
    Local<Value> v8_bool = obj->Get(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "bool"));

    char *c_str = (*String::Utf8Value(v8_string));
    int c_int = v8_int->Int32Value();
    double c_float = v8_float->NumberValue();
    bool c_bool = v8_bool->BooleanValue();

    printf("%s %d %lf %d\n",c_str, c_int, c_float, c_bool);
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(obj);
}
```

But I didn't find the same function declaration as `Local<Value> Get (Local<Value> key)` in the V8 API documentation.Only found the following similar.

```
MaybeLocal<Value> Object::Get (Local<Context> context, Local<Value> key)
```

So, where exactly is this function declaration.

V8 API DOC https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-8.9/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Right here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v8.x/deps/v8/include/v8.h#L3122

It's deprecated; you should use the function you've found instead:

```
MaybeLocal<Value> Object::Get (Local<Context> context, Local<Value> key)
```

The generated documentation apparently (and understandably) doesn't know how to deal with the V8_DEPRECATE_SOON macro, but it does list the function: https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-8.9/db/d85/classv8_1_1_object.html#ac32361a713153dc3e1349c0c31481182